# Limit sharepoint search API results to some geo locations

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-api, sharepoint-search, sharepoint-rest-api

In a multi geo environment I would like to execute a SharePoint REST API search and limit it to some geo locations only as described [in the microsoft multi geo documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/configure-search-for-multi-geo?view=o365-worldwide#get-custom-search-applications-to-show-results-from-all-or-some-geo-locations). I have tried the GET as well as POST requests, but all settings in my MultiGeoSearchConfiguration are ignored, I am always getting the full result list from all geo locations.

What am I doing wrong here? Is it maybe the missing sourceId that I have now idea of where to find?

```
curl --location -g --request GET 'https://<mydev>.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext=%27test%27&ClientType=%27cb991e32-6ce4-4e98-a91b-4eea9a874962%27&Properties=%27EnableMultiGeoSearch:true,%20MultiGeoSearchConfiguration:[{DataLocation\:%22EUR%22\,Endpoint\:%22https\://<mydev>EUR.sharepoint.com%22}]%27' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer ...'
```

(<mydev> is exchanged for my real sharepoint of course)

Answer (score 0):

In your API request, you have the **EnableMultiGeoSearch:true** and according to the documentation provided, it mentions that if this parameter is set to true, "the query shall be fanned out to the indexes of other geo locations of the multi-geo tenant", have you tried setting this value to false?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work as well - disabling MultiGeoSearch completely leaves me with results coming only from the default geo location, in this case NAM, whereas I would like to receive only data from a specific location, e.g. EUR. Maybe my example was chosen badly to show this case, will update my question. The documentation's example under 'Sample GET request to fan out to some geo locations' also keeps EnableMultiGeoSearch set to true, and then just adds the limits of locations in the MultiGeoSearchConfiguration.